# PropertyChanged is Null UWP

Tags: .net, data-binding, uwp, inotifypropertychanged, uwp-xaml

Okay, before you say anything I know multiple posts of this exist and I am searching for an answer for hours. I am a new user in Stack Overflow and fairly new to C# and UWP so please feel free to correct me.

I am making an UWP store application for Windows 10.
I using an API and I am connecting to a server.
All of that happens in a separate page of my `MainPage.xaml` which is loaded in a `Frame`!

What I want to do is to show the `string connectionStatus` to the `MainPage.xaml` (through a `<TextBlock/>`) while it is changing in my `LoginPage.xaml.cs` (which is inside the `MainPage.xaml` frame). I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
If any of those doesn't make sense please write a comment and I will try to answer.

So I have in my `MainPage.xaml` this code for the binding and the `<Page.DataContext>` for the `NotifyChanges` class (which is in my `LoginPage.xaml.cs`).

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:NotifyChanges/>
</Page.DataContext>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,10,0" Foreground="LimeGreen" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="18"/>
```

And here is my `NotifyChanges` class which is in my `LoginPage.xaml.cs` which is loaded inside a `Frame` in my `MainPage.xaml`:

```
public class NotifyChanges : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string connectionStatus = "Disconnected";

    public string ConnectionStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return connectionStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != connectionStatus)
            {
                connectionStatus = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ConnectionStatus");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, here is my code that changes the `connectionStatus` in two different places, while connecting and after connection.

```
public async Task Run()
{
    NotifyChanges notifyChanges = new NotifyChanges();

    try
    {
        userToken = TokenTextBox.Text;

        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.User, userToken);

        var connect = client.ConnectAsync();

        notifyChanges.ConnectionStatus = client.ConnectionState.ToString();

        await connect;

        notifyChanges.ConnectionStatus = client.ConnectionState.ToString();

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ChatPage), userToken);

        // Block this task until the program is exited.
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
    catch
    {
        ConnectionErrorTextBlock.Text = "Something went wrong :/ You may want to check the token again!";
    }
}
```

**Notes:**
The binding seems to work because as you can see I have set the default value to "Disconected" and it is set, but after that it never changes again.
I have debugged the program and the app goes into the NotifyChanges definition, but it never executes the notify event because `PropertyChanged` never changes from Null.
Am I missing something ? Is my error elsewhere ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something - this pice of code:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:NotifyChanges/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

and this one:

```
NotifyChanges notifyChanges = new NotifyChanges();
```

create two different references. When you work with binding you want to work on the same one reference of the class. If your `Run()` method is in the same page this may work:

```
public async Task Run()
{
    NotifyChanges notifyChanges = this.DataContext as NotifyChanges;
    // rest of the code
```

Comment: It works. Thank you man. Have been trying this for hours. Could you please explain why this happens ? The this.DataContext points at the same page which is Login.xaml.cs. The bind happens in page MainPage. How does that work ? Thank you!

Comment: @KonKarapas The binding only refers to a class from DataContext, which in your case has been created in xaml. In your solution, in Run method, you have created totally new reference, which then you have been modifying, but it's not the one from data context. The UI is bound to the one created in xaml.

Comment: @KonKarapas Note that you can also assign *NotifyChanges* in page's constructor to a suitable property, then set `this.DataContext = propertyNotifyChanges;` - then you have a property in code which you can easily modify without casting/creating (no need to set DataContext in xaml). You may also use `x:Bind` without setting *DataContext*, but it's other story - there are many blogs/posts about it.

Comment: @KonKarapas Everything depends on your needs, if you follow MVVM then you have *Model/ViewModel* with suitable properties which you change. You may create it upon app startup, load, create in resources, many options.

Comment: I shouldn't probably continue this here, but:
I moved to MVVM (still learning), and I have my ViewModels and my Views.
I cant use the this.DataContext anymore simply because my data is not in the save class. (Right?). I tried making a reference of my LoginPage class (ex LoginPage page = new LoginPage(); page.DataContext...) but that is like reloading the page which moves me into an infinite loop.

Comment: @KonKarapas Yeah, not the best place to ask, would be much better if you ask new question with showing what you have tried and where the problem is. Though maybe this will give you some ideas - if you have a ViewModel then you can probably access it from code, via property/reference, there is no need to use DataContext for that. Though everything depends on implementation and it's hard for me to say without the code -> thus new question is much better here.