# UWP INotifyPropertyChanged is null (c#)

Tags: c#, null, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

According to [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart), I'm trying to use INotifyPropertyChanged function to refresh binding data in my UWP application. Unfortunately always when the value of data is changed from code behind, event PropertyChangedEventHandler return null value (PropertyChanged = null during check this statment: if (PropertyChanged != null)). When the value is changed from application page (by enter value to TextBox) PropertyChanged is set with some value.

My class with INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    public class UserOperation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _beginDistance, _endDistance;

    public int BeginDistance {get { return _beginDistance; }
        set
        {
            _beginDistance = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BeginDistance");
        }
    }
    public int EndDistance { get { return _endDistance; }
        set
        {
            _endDistance = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EndDistance");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Implementation in code behind:

```
public sealed partial class PartCreatePage : Page
{

    private UserOperation operation { get; set; }

    public  PartCreatePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        operation = new UserOperation();

    }
    private void OperationAck_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        operation.BeginDistance = 500;
    }
```

And xaml:

```
                        <TextBox x:Name="begin_Distance" 
                             Text="{x:Bind operation.BeginDistance, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             KeyDown="onlyNumeric_KeyDown"
                             Style="{StaticResource OperationFlyout_TextBox}" />
```

Comment: How do you mean "event PropertyChangedEventHandler return null value"?

Comment: This mean that: PropertyChanged = null during check this statment: if (PropertyChanged != null)

Comment: Check that if it helps. I had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354995/propertychanged-is-null-uwp

Comment: Agree with Tóth Tibor. It seems the code should be works. If you change the data by set the value to operation.BeginDistance, the PropertyChanged will not be null.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and works flawlessly.

If you don't have any binding to the specific property it's completly right that the PropertyChanged is null, because nobody have registered event handlers to it and nobody needs to get notify about the change.

Answer (score 0):

The proper pattern is ...

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Reference: [MSDN How to Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

**Answer:**

To answer your question though, the reason your property changed handler is null is because you're not assigning the data context to your view model.

Your code should set the data context in the constructor

```
public sealed partial class PartCreatePage : Page
{

    private UserOperation operation { get; set; }

    public  PartCreatePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new UserOperation();
    }
```

After you do this your binding is wired. You *CAN* access it by calling the data context and casting it to your view model. That said, please don't do this. The whole point of the MVVM design is that you're not setting values from your view behind code.

Comment: This is a better practice, and prevents a race condition but it has nothing to do with OP's current issue.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller I'm answering the question. Give me one second

Comment: No he is using `x:Bind` so the `DataContect` isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about UWP, but for WPF it might be because you haven't specified the DataContext, so it worth a try to do next:

```
public  PartCreatePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        operation = new UserOperation();
        this.DataContext = operation;  // or UWP analog  
    }
```

And, according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) you might want to assign empty delegate to your PropertyChangedEventHandler:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

Comment: No, he is using `x:Bind` so the `DataContext` is not even used in this scenario. Also why do we want ot assign an empty delegate to the `PropertyChanged`?